# When is gcc evaluating functions at compile time?

Tags: c, gcc

When I have the following code

```
int main(void) {
        printf("%zd\n", strlen("Hello World!"));

        return 0;
}
```

and compile it with `-O3`, `strings` will show that the string "Hello World!" is missing from the binary since it got evaluated at compile time.

If I instead use my own function

```
static inline size_t my_strlen(const char *s) {
        const char *tmp = s;

        while (*++tmp);

        return tmp - s;
}

int main(void) {
        printf("%zd\n", my_strlen("Hello World!"));

        return 0;
}
```

with the same options, the string can still be found in the binary.

Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

Because it is an [optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) permitted by the standard.

On some systems, `strlen` is finally expanded to `_builtin_strlen` which is known by the GCC compiler. On my machine `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string.h` (which is *indirectly* included by `<string.h>`) has

```
# define strlen(str) \
  (__extension__ (__builtin_constant_p (str)         \
                 ? __builtin_strlen (str)            \
                 : __strlen_g (str)))
```

So actually is it done by the mix of GNU `glibc` and `gcc`

Comment: With the reason that `my_strlen` can't be similarly optimised presumably being that it's difficult for a compiler to spot that it's fully deterministic and has no side effects? Whereas the well-defined C library functions have well-defined behaviours?

Comment: There seems to be more compiler magic. Even if I use `size_t strlen(const char *);` instead of `#include <string.h>` or parenthesize `(strlen)` to suppress macro expansion, the assembler output still contains neither the string literal nor an actual call to `strlen` (gcc 4.7.2 and 4.9.2).

Answer (score 2):

GCC probably has an optimization somewhere that replaces the strlen() of a constant string with the length of that string.

When you use your own function, this optimization cannot be turned on. GCC does not know if the `my_strlen` has side-effects, so it has to run it each time.

Comment: Specifically it has `-foptimize-strlen` which "[o]ptimize[s] various standard C string functions (e.g. strlen, strchr or strcpy) ... into faster alternatives." with knowing the answer being a much faster alternative. Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html