# Is strlen Optimized out for String Literals?

Tags: c++, c-strings, string-length, string-literals, compile-time-constant

So say that I have this:

```
const auto foo = "lorem ipsum"
```

If I use `strlen(foo)` in my code, is the 11 found at run time or is that injected at compile time?

Comment: You can ask https://godbolt.org/. Edit : It seems gcc 8.1 will preform that optimization : https://godbolt.org/g/8nrkQb

Comment: Consider writing a `constexpr` version, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389936/strlen-compile-time-optimization).

Comment: Most good compilers will do that optimization to a constant 11 (at least when the optimizer is turned on), but it's not *guaranteed*.

Comment: Here is a [gcc-specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27194501/335858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard doesn't allow implementations to add constexpr, except where it is explicitly required:

> [constexpr.functions]
>   This document explicitly requires that certain standard library functions are constexpr ([dcl.constexpr]).
>   An implementation shall not declare any standard library function signature as constexpr except for those where it is explicitly required.

So `strlen` is out of bounds.

However, to support `constexpr` constructors of `string_view`, the C++17 standard requires that certain members of `char_traits`, like [`char_traits::length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length),  are constexpr anyway.

And this month we have had new compiler releases of [gcc 8.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html)  and [MSVC 15.7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/07/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-c-standard/) so that the latest versions of the major compilers now all implement `char_traits::length` as constexpr.

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on the compiler and the current optimization level.

A quick experiment with this C++ code

```
#include <cstring>
int strlen_of_const() {
    return strlen("lorem ipsum");
}
```

on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) reveals, that some compilers would optimize out the call, while other compilers would make the call at runtime. For example, gcc optimizes out the call:

```
strlen_of_const():
  mov eax, 11
  ret
```

MSVC, on the other hand, keeps the call:

```
$SG3533 DB        'lorem ipsum', 00H
EXTRN   strlen:PROC
strlen_of_const PROC
        sub      rsp, 40              ; 00000028H
        lea      rcx, OFFSET FLAT:$SG3533
        call     strlen
        add      rsp, 40              ; 00000028H
        ret      0
strlen_of_const ENDP
```

Comment: I guess this makes sense. There'd have to be some sort of `constexpr size_t strlen(const char*)` function overload to guarantee this would happen. Thus I cannot depend upon this occurring.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on your compiler and whether or not you are building with optimizations enabled.

A good modern compiler is likely to optimize the `strlen` away and produce 11 as a constant when optimizing, but nothing in the language forces it to. So it's also perfectly valid for the compiler to generate a function call.

You just have to test with your compiler of choice at your optimization level of choice and read the generated assembly.